# Magento : How to get dropdown text using angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, magento

I have a drop-down for the Fractions.

Like This:

```
<label for="fraction">Fraction</label>
<select id="fraction">
  <options value="1"> 1/8 </options>
  <options value="2" selected="selected"><b> 1/4 </b></options>
  <options value="2"> 1/4</options>
</select>
```

This is already I have, mean drop-down list is dynamic not static !

Now, I want to get selected text **1/4** of drop-down using angularjs!

In Angularjs says to set value using the controller in json, **but I want to get selected text as per the jQuery !**

So, Is there any one can help me for this !

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: jquery is not angular. Why not use the angular functions?

Comment: I use angular, but Can you give me an example of it !